# Hibernate @ManyToOne relation with @JoinTable and inheritance

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, join

[Hibernate - 4.1.9.Final]
[MySQL driver]

Hi, I have the following entities.

**ANIMAL :**

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "ANIMAL" )
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS )
public abstract class Animal implements Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.TABLE )
@Column( name = "ANIMAL_ID" )
public Long id;

@Column( name = "ANIMAL_NAME" )
public String name;

}
```

**DOG :**

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "DOG" )
public class Dog extends Animal implements Cloneable, Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManyToOne
@JoinTable( name = "DOG_OTHER_DOG" )
public Dog dog;

}
```

With a cyclic relationship on Dog entity.

```
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinTable( name = "DOG_OTHER_DOG" )
 public Dog dog;
```

Next, I'm trying to persist a new dog using Hibernate Session API.

```
 @Transactional
 public void testAnimalJoinTable()
 {
      Dog dogFirst = new Dog();
      dogFirst.name = "FirstDog";

      Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
      session.save( dogFirst );

      Dog dogSecond = new Dog();
      dogSecond.dog = dogFirst;
      dogSecond.name = "SecondDog";

      session.save( dogSecond );
 }
```

Schema is well created

> Hibernate: create table DOG (ANIMAL_ID bigint not null, ANIMAL_NAME varchar(255), primary key (ANIMAL_ID)) ENGINE=InnoDB
>   Hibernate: create table DOG_OTHER_DOG (dog_ANIMAL_ID bigint, ANIMAL_ID bigint not null, primary key (ANIMAL_ID)) ENGINE=InnoDB

But finally, Hibernate always fails on the save method and throws.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'dog_ANIMAL_ID' in 'field list'

Indeed, Hibernate don't use the join table to save the dog.

> Hibernate: select sequence_next_hi_value from hibernate_sequences where sequence_name = 'ANIMAL' for update
>   Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequences(sequence_name, sequence_next_hi_value) values('ANIMAL', ?)
>   Hibernate: update hibernate_sequences set sequence_next_hi_value = ? where sequence_next_hi_value = ? and sequence_name = 'ANIMAL'
>   Hibernate: insert into DOG (ANIMAL_NAME, dog_ANIMAL_ID, ANIMAL_ID) values (?, ?, ?)

Well, my question is (:

- Why did Hibernate do not use the join table ? **(everything works fine if I delete Animal inheritance)**
- In my case, How can I solve the problem ?

Thanks in advance !

---

PS : I can't use @MappedSuperclass to solve this issue..